# Trouble Loading Google Charts Treemap and Bubble Chart on same page

Tags: html, google-visualization, treemap, bubble-chart

Trying to put both a treemap and bubble chart on the same page, both work individually, but not together. Tried a bunch of different things, but not sure if I am defining the two separate things properly.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.load('visualization', "1", {packages: ['treemap']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
            [
              ["State","Percent of GDP","Average Freshman Graduation Rate","Region","Expenditure ($ millions)"],
              ["Alabama",0.214,71.8,"Southeast",5165],
              ["Alaska",0.135,75.5,"Far West",1635],
              ["Arizona",0.186,74.7,"Southwest",5454],
              ["Arkansas",0.155,75,"Southeast",3342],
              ["California",0.209,78.2,"Far West",47674],
              ["Colorado",0.265,79.8,"Rocky Mountain",7547],
              ["Connecticut",0.14,75.1,"New England",3930],
              ["Deleware",0.243,75.5,"Mid-Atlantic",2227],
              ["Florida",0.181,70.8,"Southeast",12636],
              ["Georgia",0.241,69.9,"Southeast",9916],
              ["Hawaii",0.155,75.4,"Far West",1794],
              ["Idaho",0.226,84,"Rocky Mountain",1634],
              ["Illinois",0.144,81.9,"Greater Lakes",9588],
              ["Indiana",0.313,77.2,"Greater Lakes",8680],
              ["Iowa",0.166,87.9,"Plains",3251],
              ["Kansas",0.259,84.5,"Plains",3737],
              ["Kentucky",0.196,79.9,"Southeast",5021],
              ["Louisiana",0.181,68.8,"Southeast",5367],
              ["Maine",0.166,82.8,"New England",1297],
              ["Maryland",0.191,82.2,"Mid-Atlantic",7073],
              ["Massachusetts",0.106,82.6,"New England",6402],
              ["Michigan",0.268,75.9,"Greater Lakes",13059],
              ["Minnesota",0.272,88.2,"Plains",9729],
              ["Mississippi",0.163,63.8,"Southeast",3174],
              ["Missouri",0.228,83.7,"Plains",5229],
              ["Montana",0.155,81.9,"Rocky Mountain",936],
              ["Nebraska",0.146,83.8,"Plains",1488],
              ["Nevada",0.222,57.8,"Far West",1976],
              ["New Hampshire",0.233,86.3,"New England",1171],
              ["New Jersey",0.243,87.2,"Mid-Atlantic",12651],
              ["New Mexico",0.197,67.3,"Southwest",2870],
              ["New York",0.193,76,"Mid-Atlantic",25657],
              ["North Carolina",0.206,76.9,"Southeast",10605],
              ["North Dakota",0.143,88.4,"Plains",851],
              ["Ohio",0.198,81.4,"Greater Lakes",11515],
              ["Oklahoma",0.162,78.5,"Southwest",3474],
              ["Oregon",0.143,76.3,"Far West",3680],
              ["Pennsylvania",0.189,84.1,"Mid-Atlantic",12820],
              ["Rhode Island",0.149,76.4,"New England",1209],
              ["South Carolina",0.175,68.2,"Southeast",3903],
              ["South Dakota",0.14,81.8,"Plains",578],
              ["Tennessee",0.178,80.4,"Southeast",5609],
              ["Texas",0.27,78.9,"Southwest",26163],
              ["Utah",0.245,78.6,"Rocky Mountain",3091],
              ["Vermont",0.325,91.4,"New England",1613],
              ["Virginia",0.155,81.2,"Southeast",6928],
              ["Washington",0.237,77.2,"Far West",7873],
              ["West Virginia",0.095,78.3,"Southeast",2221],
              ["Wisconsin",0.162,91.1,"Greater Lakes",6935],
              ["Wyoming",0.055,80.3,"Rocky Mountain",474]
            ]);

            var data2 =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Location", "Parent", "Spending in $millions (size)"],
                ["United States", null, 340852],
                ["New England", "United States", 15622],
                ["Connecticut", "New England", 3930],
                ["Maine", "New England", 1297],
                ["Massachusetts", "New England", 6402],
                ["New Hampshire", "New England", 1171],
                ["Rhode Island", "New England", 1209],
                ["Vermont", "New England", 1613],
                ["Mid-Atlantic", "United States", 60428],
                ["Deleware", "Mid-Atlantic", 2227],
                ["Maryland", "Mid-Atlantic", 7073],
                ["New Jersey", "Mid-Atlantic", 12651],
                ["New York", "Mid-Atlantic", 25657],
                ["Pennsylvania", "Mid-Atlantic", 12820],
                ["Greater Lakes", "United States", 49777],
                ["Illinois", "Greater Lakes", 9588],
                ["Indiana", "Greater Lakes", 8680],
                ["Michigan", "Greater Lakes", 13059],
                ["Ohio", "Greater Lakes", 11515],
                ["Wisconsin", "Greater Lakes", 6935],
                ["Plains", "United States", 24863],
                ["Iowa", "Plains", 3251],
                ["Kansas", "Plains", 3737],
                ["Minnesota", "Plains", 9729],
                ["Missouri", "Plains", 5229],
                ["Nebraska", "Plains", 1488],
                ["North Dakota", "Plains", 851],
                ["South Dakota", "Plains", 578],
                ["Southeast", "United States", 73887],
                ["Alabama", "Southeast", 5165],
                ["Arkansas", "Southeast", 3342],
                ["Florida", "Southeast", 12636],
                ["Georgia", "Southeast", 9916],
                ["Kentucky", "Southeast", 5021],
                ["Louisiana", "Southeast", 5367],
                ["Mississippi", "Southeast", 3174],
                ["North Carolina", "Southeast", 10605],
                ["South Carolina", "Southeast", 3903],
                ["Tennessee", "Southeast", 5609],
                ["Virginia", "Southeast", 6928],
                ["West Virginia", "Southeast", 2221],
                ["Southwest", "United States", 37961],
                ["Arizona", "Southwest", 5454],
                ["New Mexico", "Southwest", 2870],
                ["Oklahoma", "Southwest", 3474],
                ["Texas", "Southwest", 26163],
                ["Rocky Mountain", "United States", 13682],
                ["Colorado", "Rocky Mountain", 7547],
                ["Idaho", "Rocky Mountain", 1634],
                ["Montana", "Rocky Mountain", 936],
                ["Utah", "Rocky Mountain", 3091],
                ["Wyoming", "Rocky Mountain", 474],
                ["Far West", "United States", 64632],
                ["Alaska", "Far West", 1635],
                ["California", "Far West", 47674],
                ["Hawaii", "Far West", 1794],
                ["Nevada", "Far West", 1976],
                ["Oregon", "Far West", 3680],
                ["Washington", "Far West", 7873]
            ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Correlation between Average Freshman Graduation Rate (After Four Years of High School), Percentage of GDP Spent on Education, and State Expenditure on Education (2013)',
          hAxis: {title: 'Percent of GDP'},
          vAxis: {title: 'AFGR'},
          bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
        };

        var options2 = {};

        var chart = google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

        var tree = google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            tree.draw(data, {
                headerHeight: 15,
                fontColor: 'black',
                showScale: true
            });
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single call to `google.load` that loads both packages:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:['corechart', 'treemap']});
```